# How do i drop the 0, 1 and 2?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count, drop

I have the code below trying to check `dob_years` for suspicious values and count the percentage

```
df['dob_years'].value_counts()
```

The result is below

```
35    614
41    603
40    603
34    597
38    595
42    592
33    577
39    572
31    556
36    553
44    543
29    543
30    536
48    536
37    531
43    510
50    509
32    506
49    505
28    501
45    494
27    490
52    483
56    482
47    480
54    476
46    469
58    461
57    457
53    457
51    446
55    441
59    441
26    406
60    376
25    356
61    353
62    351
63    268
24    263
64    263
23    252
65    194
66    183
22    183
67    167
21    110
0     100
68     99
69     83
2      76
70     65
71     58
20     51
1      47
72     33
19     14
73      8
74      6
75      1
```

How do I drop the ages showing as 0, 1, and 2?

I tried the code below but it didn't work

```
df.drop(df[(df['dob_years'] = 0) & (df['dob_years'] = 1)].index, inplace=True)
```

Comment: I think you're after `df[~df['dob_years'].isin([0, 1, 2])`

Comment: Note that your existing code is attempting to AND the conditions... the year can't be both 0 and 1 at the same time... if you were to change the `&` to `|` you'd be closer...

Comment: In addition to the points mentioned by @Jon Clements, you need double `==` to check for equality. To check for a range, `df[~df.dob_years.between(0, 2)]` would work, too.

Comment: Am I using the df. drop in addition to that? I have tried the above codes and it did not change.

Answer (score 0):

This statement `df['dob_years'].value_counts()` takes a series and returns another series. The result in your question is a series with index as **dob_years** and the **counts** as value array.

To follow the suggestions from *Jon Clements* and others, you will have to convert it in to a DataFrame using the `to_frame` function. Consider this code:

```
import pandas as pd

# create the data frame
df = pd.read_csv('dob.csv')

# create count series and convert it in to a DataFrame
df1 = df['dob_years'].value_counts().to_frame("counts")

# convert DataFrame index in to a column
df1.reset_index(inplace=True)

# rename the column index to dob_years
df1 = df1.rename(columns = {'index':'dob_years'})

# dropping the required rows from DataFrame
df1 = df1[~df1['dob_years'].isin([0, 1, 2])]
print(df1)
```